# Elasticsearch .search object return error in Python3

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I must be missing something. When I do a elastic.search(index='parole', q='sometext'), I got an object returned. I am trying to get the element inside this object

```
data=elastic.search(index='parole', q='sometext')
mydata=data['hits']['hits']
```

That is working perfectly.

But if I am doing:

```
mydata['_source']
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> mydata=data['hits']['hits']
>>> mydata
    [{'_id': '6', '_source': {'parole_de_la_chanson': " Blabla", 'titre_chanson':  'Allo Maman Bobo', 'numero_id_json': 'key6', 'nom_du_chanteur': ' 'Alain Souchon '}, '_index': 'parole', '_type': 'string', '_score': 0.2802974}]
```

Comment: print `mydata` between those two lines and tell us the result.

Comment: Thanks. Ok. I ve updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `data` is a list.  I *would* say, try `mydata = data[0]['hits']['hits']`, but it doesn't look like 'hits' is in that list at all, even in the dictionary.

Comment: I ve made a mistake when I update mydata. What I want is acces '_source' and then 'parole_de_la_chanson'

Comment: In that case, try `mydata = data[0]['_source']['parole_de_la_chanson']`.

Comment: In fact it is: 'mydata[0]['_source']['parole_de_la_chanson']' thanks for your help.